# Rails3 custom route format

Tags: routes, ruby-on-rails-3

In routes.rb I was forced to add:

```
post 'admin/user_update'
```

to get my form_tag to work:

```
form_tag( { :action => :update_user, :id => @user.id }, :remote => :true )
```

Now I get:

```
Template is missing

Missing template admin/update_user with {:handlers=>[:erb, :rjs, :builder,
:rhtml, :rxml], :formats=>[:html], :locale=>[:en, :en]} in view paths
"/rails/test/app/views"
```

My template is update_user.js.erb:

```
$('#user-edit-<%= @user.id %>').html("&nbsp;");
$('#tr-user-edit-<%= @user.id %>').hide();
```

How can I get the route to accept that I want to process the request using js?

How can I add js to the :formats?

Please do not use the word "resources" in your reply.  I'm aware this is a custom route.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, this is a jquery issue (though you never explicitly mentioned jquery)

Try adding:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajaxSetup({ 
        'beforeSend': function(xhr) {xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "text/javascript")}
    });
});
```

to your application.js file.

Answer (score 0):

You can add

match 'update_user/:id' => 'admin#update_user', :as => :update_user, :via => :put

to your routes.

In view, you can do,

```
form_for(@user, :url => update_user_path(@user.id), :remote => true) do |f|
.
.
.
```

I think as per request type, it should pick up appropriate format file, else
you can do is after your controller code,

```
def update_user
  .
  .
  .
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```